# Solve $y=(2y^4+2x)y'$ using Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, laplace-transform

My attempt:
\begin{align*}
\mathscr{L}\{y&=(2y^4+2x)y'\}\\
Y&=2\mathscr{L}\{y^4y'\}+2\mathscr{L}\{xy'\}\\
\end{align*}
Consider
\begin{align*}
\mathscr{L}\{y'\}&=sY-Y(0)\\
\int_0^\infty y'e^{-sx}dx&=sY-Y(0)\\
\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial s}(y'e^{-sx})dx&=\dfrac{d}{ds}(sY-Y(0))\\
\mathscr{L}\{xy'\}&=-(x\frac{dY}{ds}+Y)
\end{align*}
I can't think of a way to evaluate $\mathscr{L}\{y^4y'\}$ and to continue solving differential equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y=(2y^4+2x)y'$$
Rewrite the differential equation as:
$$x'y=2y^4+2x$$
Then you can apply the Laplace transform.
$$X'(s)+2X(s)=-\dfrac {2 \times 4!}{s^5}$$